# django rest framework - filtering against date query parameter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-rest-viewsets

In my view I'm receiving `date` parameter and I'm filtering against it so I could show my contact for today, and it goes something like this:

```
filter_date = self.request.query_params.get('filter_date', None)

for queryset in contact_lead:
   if filter_date is not None:
       queryset = queryset.filter(next_action_date__gte=filter_date)

return queryset
```

Like I said with this I can see my contacts for today, but there are some contact that are made in the past, now because `datepicker` have past dates restriction I can not see them and I want all my past contact to appear today, or any other day in the future, so the point is I don't want contact which are created in the past to be left behind, so can someone help me and explain how can I get that result.

Comment: replace __gte with __lte

Comment: ok this was embarrassing, that did the trick :-|

Comment: haha. happens! Can you help me reach 1k rep points? I ll answer the same and do accept it..

Comment: @AbijithMg shure, you can give me a detailed explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace greater than or equal to(`__gte`) with less than or equal to(**`__lte`**) in the query lookup. As shown below:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(next_action_date__lte=filter_date)
```

This will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are two operators to do this  one is less than or equal to(__lte)

As given below:

```
 queryset = queryset.filter(next_action_date__lte=filter_date)
```

Second one is less than (__le),

This will not give the current Filter Condition

```
 queryset = queryset.filter(next_action_date__lt=filter_date)
```